# CSS elements do not work when using redux

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

There is a simple notes application using react js and redux

I have a note card component with css properties:

**`NoteItem.js`**

```
const NoteItem = ({ text, date, index }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deleteNoteItem = () => {
    dispatch(deleteNote(index));
  };

  return (
    <div className={"note"}>
      <span>{text}</span>
      <div className="note-footer">
        <small>{date}</small>
        <MdDeleteForever
          className={"delete-icon"}
          size={"1.3em"}
          onClick={deleteNoteItem}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS properties

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+2&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'M PLUS 2', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
  monospace;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
}

.dark-mode h1 {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.notes-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
        auto-fill,
    minmax(250px, 1fr)
    );
}

.note.new {
  background-color: #67d7cc;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  background-color: #67d7cc;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.save {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.save:hover {
  background-color: #ededed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.note {
  background-color: #fef68a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 170px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.note-footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.delete-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.search input {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  width: 100%;
}

.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

**`NewItem.js`**

```
  const NewItem = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const getCurrentDate = () => {
      const date = new Date();
      return `${date.getDate()}-${
        date.getMonth() + 1
      }-${date.getFullYear()}  ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`;
    };

    const add = () => {
      dispatch(
        addNote({
          text: input,
          date: getCurrentDate()
        })
      );

      setInput("")
    };

    return (
      <div className={"note new"}>
        <textarea
          rows={"8"}
          cols={"10"}
          placeholder={"Type to add a note..."}
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className={"note-footer"}>
          <small>{200 - input.length} remaining</small>
          <button className="save" onClick={add}>
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};
```

If i hardcode the text in span tag in the card component, the card looks like it's supposed to

[image: Card item]

But if I integrate the logic to create a new card into the redux component then the card is rendered this way:

[image: Card item using redux]

What could be the problem? I haven't found anything like that here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess `NoteItem` is what you are calling a "card"?  Try logging `text` in the `NoteItem` component before the return statement (`console.log(text)`).  I suspect your redux value doesn't have spaces.  Or conversely, if you hard code the lorem ipsum text with semicolons instead of spaces, it'll probably look bad as well.

Comment: By the way, you may want to pad the day, month and minutes parts of your timestamps with 0's using `String.prototype.padStart` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your note's `span` automatically breaks at spaces to avoid overflow. It seems you didn't put any whitespace in your second example, causing the overflow.

To break at the edge of the span anyway, add the css property `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to your note class.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text#breaking_long_words

Here's the fiddle I tested the change in https://jsfiddle.net/febargph/

Answer (score 0):

this is how a long string what has no spaces behaves inside a `<span>` . add spaces to it, it will also help
css property `word-break`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break